# Google Distance Matrix API arrival time

Tags: android, web-services, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to get the arrival time parameter for the Google Distance Matrix API and I don't understand how to pass data to it. I am trying to make an app to show me what time to leave from somewhere to arrive on time to another place. Does just getting the information in the API violate their terms of usage? 
example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Pawtucket+Rhode+Island&destinations=North+Attleboro+Massachusetts&arrival_time=Dec+5+2015+8+PM&key=YOUR_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer is a little late for the original post, hopefully it'll still be useful to others... As per the [Google Maps APIs Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters):

> `arrival_time` — Specifies the desired time of arrival for transit requests, in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. You can specify either `departure_time` or `arrival_time`, but not both. Note that `arrival_time` must be specified as an **integer**.

I suggest doing a calculation in Excel to calculate the number of seconds since 1970 - it can easily get a bit messy, so it's a shame that there's no more 'user-friendly' way to pass the date.

Additionally, I'm not certain whether the `arrival_time` parameter will definitely work for you - I wanted to use it myself using a call to `DistanceMatrix` through the JavaScript API and there, it requires a Premium Plan account, but perhaps it's okay directly through the DistanceMatrix API.

Also, the [JavaScript DistanceMatrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests) states that the arrival_time has to be in the future, which makes sense.